# Send HTTP POST request to Segment.io from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run, segment-io

I am trying to send HTTPS Post Request from GCP to Segment.io

I want to create a service that will read data from BigQuery table and then send calls directly to Segment.io API ([link](https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/server/http-api/#batch)) from where I'll redirect the data to other destinations, but on the GCP site I'm struggling to find the most optimal way to do it. [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses) seems like a good option but I'm wondering if there might be an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended products to be used for this task can be either [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/) or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/).

You can either use the [Client Libraries or API in order to extract the data from the BigQuery table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) and use any HTTP request library of your favorite programming language to issue the POST request to the Segment.io API.